# Will MathJax render LaTeX in a username?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

Is MathJax only applied to Q&A parts of a page or will it also get rendered in displayed user names?

Answer (score 13):

Yes, when called normally, MathJax will render everything on the page.

Also no, because user names are not allowed to contain dollar signs.

Comment: Is an @ allowed?